# Print in python 3.4.2

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3

I have typed print ("Hello World!") into python 3.4.2 and instead of printing Hello World!  It prints Syntax error: invalid character in identifier. I am a complete beginner and am using a raspberry pi 3

Comment: Oops, sorry the title says 3.5.2 it should say 3.4.2!

Comment: Chances are you typed something else, as weird as that may sound. Can you share a screenshot? Can you reproduce the problem with `print(1)`?

Comment: What text editor are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You used the wrong quotes. You must use ASCII quotes, not extended quotes.

```
>>> print ("Hello World")
Hello World
>>> print (“Hello World”)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print (“Hello World”)
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
```

Comment: Chances are @Louis Kirk did not input the fancy quotes on their keyboard,
 but they were auto-replaced by some kind of input "assistance". If that "assistant" automatically rewrites double quotes, single quotes (`'`) may be worth a try.

Answer (score -1):

For python, there are two ways to print something. You can either print a variable as a integer, string, float, and boolean

```
x=5 #int
y="Hello world" #str
z=3.14 #float
a=True #boolean
print(x)
print(y)
print(z)
print(a)

'''
output:
5
Hello World
3.14
True
'''
```

or you can directly print an integer, string, boolean, and/or float by putting it in the parenthesis like you did.

```
print(5) #int
print("Hello world!") #str
print(True) #bool
print(3.14) #float

'''
output:
5
Hello world!
True
3.14
'''
```

your code seems to be correct, there's nothing wrong with it. Make sure you put quotes around the string.

Comment: This is incorrect: If you count variables and literals as different ways, there are more ways, for example function calls. But really there is only one way; every argument to the `print` function should be an [expression](https://docs.python.org/dev/reference/expressions.html).